# Run Drupal in localhost then migrate to online once it's finalized

Tags: 7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to migrate from test environment to production environment?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/how-to-migrate-from-test-environment-to-production-environment)

I'm sure a lot of template designers work in localhost before going online. My question is **what's the best way to take your installation online once you're done playing around with it?** Do you redo everything or do you just copy your localhost db then import it online?

I'm using XAMPP in case it matters. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Since this is mostly likely a one time move (because the online version with likely be your master now) I wouldn't worry too much about perfecting the process. Just...

1. Dump the mySQL DB and place within the root.
2. Zip/Tar the codebase, including the files directory.
3. Move it to the server (via SCP or FTP), unzip/untar the whole thing.
4. Import the DB via: `mysql -hHOST -uUSER -pPASS DBNAME < db.mysql`
5. Bam!

For continual workflow I usually use:

- Backup & Migrate to create database backups.
- Git to move the code around (.gitignore your files directory)

Answer (score 1):

For a first installation, just exporting/importing a database dump usually works fine. See [Copying Drupal to a webhosting service](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/copying-drupal-to-a-webhosting-service) for more details.

After that, it gets tricker, have a look at other questions like [How to migrate from test environment to production environment?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/how-to-migrate-from-test-environment-to-production-environment).